# Disassembly view of C# 64-bit Release code is 75% longer than 32-bit Debug code?

Tags: c#, assembly, compiler-construction, visual-studio-2012, disassembly

**EDIT**

I tested release in 32 bit, and the code was compact. Therefore the below is a 64 bit issue.

---

I'm using VS 2012 RC. Debug is 32 bit, and Release is 64 bit. Below is the debug then release disassembly of a line of code:

```
         crc = (crc >> 8) ^ crcTable[((val & 0x0000ff00) >> 8) ^ crc & 0xff];
0000006f  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-40h] 
00000072  shr         eax,8 
00000075  mov         edx,dword ptr [ebp-3Ch] 
00000078  mov         ecx,0FF00h 
0000007d  and         edx,ecx 
0000007f  shr         edx,8 
00000082  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-40h] 
00000085  mov         ebx,0FFh 
0000008a  and         ecx,ebx 
0000008c  xor         edx,ecx 
0000008e  mov         ecx,dword ptr ds:[03387F38h] 
00000094  cmp         edx,dword ptr [ecx+4] 
00000097  jb          0000009E 
00000099  call        6F54F5EC 
0000009e  xor         eax,dword ptr [ecx+edx*4+8] 
000000a2  mov         dword ptr [ebp-40h],eax
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
         crc = (crc >> 8) ^ crcTable[((val & 0x0000ff00) >> 8) ^ crc & 0xff];
000000a5  mov         eax,dword ptr [rsp+20h] 
000000a9  shr         eax,8 
000000ac  mov         dword ptr [rsp+38h],eax 
000000b0  mov         rdx,124DEE68h 
000000ba  mov         rdx,qword ptr [rdx] 
000000bd  mov         eax,dword ptr [rsp+00000090h] 
000000c4  and         eax,0FF00h 
000000c9  shr         eax,8 
000000cc  mov         ecx,dword ptr [rsp+20h] 
000000d0  and         ecx,0FFh 
000000d6  xor         eax,ecx 
000000d8  mov         ecx,eax 
000000da  mov         qword ptr [rsp+40h],rdx 
000000df  mov         rax,qword ptr [rsp+40h] 
000000e4  mov         rax,qword ptr [rax+8] 
000000e8  mov         qword ptr [rsp+48h],rcx 
000000ed  cmp         qword ptr [rsp+48h],rax 
000000f2  jae         0000000000000100 
000000f4  mov         rax,qword ptr [rsp+48h] 
000000f9  mov         qword ptr [rsp+48h],rax 
000000fe  jmp         0000000000000105 
00000100  call        000000005FA5D364 
00000105  mov         rax,qword ptr [rsp+40h] 
0000010a  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rsp+48h] 
0000010f  mov         ecx,dword ptr [rax+rcx*4+10h] 
00000113  mov         eax,dword ptr [rsp+38h] 
00000117  xor         eax,ecx 
00000119  mov         dword ptr [rsp+20h],eax
```

What is all the extra code in the 64 bit version doing? It is testing for what? I haven't benchmarked this, but the 32 bit code should execute much faster.

**EDIT**

The whole function:

```
public static uint CRC32(uint val)
{
    uint crc = 0xffffffff;

    crc = (crc >> 8) ^ crcTable[(val & 0x000000ff) ^ crc & 0xff];
    crc = (crc >> 8) ^ crcTable[((val & 0x0000ff00) >> 8) ^ crc & 0xff];
    crc = (crc >> 8) ^ crcTable[((val & 0x00ff0000) >> 16) ^ crc & 0xff];
    crc = (crc >> 8) ^ crcTable[(val >> 24) ^ crc & 0xff];

    // flip bits
    return (crc ^ 0xffffffff);
}
```

Comment: It would help to see the entire function, not just the single line of it.

Comment: Trying to compare differences when one is built for debug and the other release is invalid. Compare at least the same species (debug/debug or release/release).

Comment: @KenWhite I agree. But it's the fact that debug is more compact that caught my attention, plus the fact release added checks.

Comment: The check is to see whether the index for `crcTable[]` exceeds the maximum allowed value or not (looks, like unnecessary here). I'm not quite sure why there's more code in the 64-bit version, though.

Comment: @KirkWoll this is 32 bit code. There isn't a single 64 bit op. And if you read the disassembly, you can see extra checks are added. To just say "of course 64 bit is bigger" is inaccurate and doesn't explain the disassembly at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect you are using "Go to disassembly" while debugging the release build to get the assembly code.

After going to Tools -> Options, Debugging, General, and disabling "Suppress JIT optimization on module load" I got an x64 assembly listing without error checking.

It seems like by default even in release mode the code is not optimized if the debugger attached. Keep that in mind when trying to benchmark your code.

PS: Benchmarking shows x64 slightly faster than x86, 4.3 vs 4.8 seconds for 1 billion function calls.

Edit: Break points still worked for me, otherwise I wouldn't have been able to see the disassembly after unchecking. Your example line from above looks like this (VS 2012 RC):

```
crc = (crc >> 8) ^ crcTable[((val & 0x0000ff00) >> 8) ^ crc & 0xff];
00000030  mov         r11d,eax 
00000033  shr         r11d,8 
00000037  mov         ecx,edx 
00000039  and         ecx,0FF00h 
0000003f  shr         ecx,8 
00000042  movzx       eax,al 
00000045  xor         ecx,eax 
00000047  mov         eax,ecx 
00000049  cmp         rax,r9 
0000004c  jae         00000000000000A4 
0000004e  mov         eax,dword ptr [r8+rax*4+10h] 
00000053  xor         r11d,eax
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct. So it seems that in 64 bit release debug mode, checks are added, but not in 32 bit mode. Therefore the actual release will be "clean".

Comment: Naturally, with that option disabled, "Go to disassembly" and break points stop working, so I can't check. But I believe you answered the question, backed up by your benchmarks.

Comment: I have no idea how you are getting breakpoints to work and can see the disassembly. Are you running 64 bit release? Which VS?

Comment: @IanC Maybe the function call is inlined and breakpoints start behaving weird. Try putting it to the calling function, or the function calling that function.

Comment: I can't even put a breakpoint on Form1 code. My solution is a little complex, though. 1 Win form project + 4 dll projects, of which the code in question is in a dll project.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code this is related to the error checking for accessing crcTable. It's doing your bounds before it starts digging into the array.

In the the 32-bit code you see this

```
0000008e  mov         ecx,dword ptr ds:[03387F38h] 
....
0000009e  xor         eax,dword ptr [ecx+edx*4+8]
```

In this case it's loading the base address of the array from 03387F38h and then using standard pointer arithmetic to access the correct entry.

In the 64-bit code this seems to be more complicated.

```
000000b0  mov         rdx,124DEE68h 
000000ba  mov         rdx,qword ptr [rdx]
```

This loads an address into the rdx register

```
000000da  mov         qword ptr [rsp+40h],rdx 
...
00000105  mov         rax,qword ptr [rsp+40h] 
0000010a  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rsp+48h] 
0000010f  mov         ecx,dword ptr [rax+rcx*4+10h]
```

This moves the address onto the stack, then later on it moves it into the rax register and does the same pointer work to access the array.

Pretty much everything between 000000da and 00000100/00000105 seems to be validation code. The rest of the code maps pretty well between the 64-bit and the 32-bit code, with some less aggressive register utilization in the 64-bit code.

Comment: I made an edit: I tested the release mode in 32 bit, and the output was identical to 32 bit debug: short. This is certainly a 64 bit issue.

Comment: @IanC Ah, good to know. I updated the answer to take that into account.

Comment: This is really unexpected. Building in 32 bit mode will clearly result in faster code. Now I'm wondering if 64 bit code is riddled with array bounds check and complex access code.

Comment: @IanC array bounds checks are always there, even in release mode. The program is required to throw ArgumentOutOfRangeException in case the index exceeds the array size. The compiler maybe could (in this case) prove that the exception will never happen, but it does not seem to do this. I think most of the seemingly unnecessary instructions we have here only serve the purpose of making the life of the debugger easier by tracking all variables (and temporaries?) in memory instead of just keeping them in registers.

Answer (score 0):

exp ^ crc & 0xff is compiled as exp ^ (cr & 0xff):

```
00000082  mov         ecx,dword ptr [ebp-40h]  
00000085  mov         ebx,0FFh  
0000008a  and         ecx,ebx  
0000008c  xor         edx,ecx
```

Should you write the expression as ?

```
(exp ^ crc) & 0xff
```

The 64-bit version is definitely less optimized than the 32-bit version. CLR has two seperate JIT compiler implementation.

Also, if perf is criticial, use unsafe code to remove bounds check.

Comment: Apparently the full release in 64 bit is 12% faster than the 32 bit. The answer is the attached debugger prevented optimizations in 64 bit, but not 32. Just the way it's set up. The code is standard CRC.