# Why is C# Release 3x slower when launched from VS2010 IDE?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, performance, release, launch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Disassembly view of C# 64-bit Release code is 75% longer than 32-bit Debug code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12397108/disassembly-view-of-c-sharp-64-bit-release-code-is-75-longer-than-32-bit-debug)

I have an extremely simple C# Console Application, hat does some sorting on a big number of elements (only a few lines of code with array operations).

When I start the release code from Visual Studio IDE with F5 or Ctrl-F5 the program is about 3x slower than when started directly from Win-Explorer.

```
41.140 seconds when launched from VS 2010 IDE
13.950 seconds when launched by double-clicking myprogram.exe
```

Why???

Comment: How do you measure? And how do you launch? Start debug in Release mode, or how?

Comment: It was measured with Stopwatch. The reason is, that CS always attaches a debugger when starting with F5 - no matter whether in debug or in release mode. In C++ this is different!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting a program with the debugger attached will always be significantly slower than without it.

Comment: Yepp, it is definitively the debugger. I did not know that VS attaches a debugger also in Release-Mode. When I start in Release-Mode with Ctrl-F5 it runs fast!!!

Answer (score 6):

First some details...

Be aware that there are 2 main "optimization" stages in .NET.

- At the C# Compiler level
  ...the production of different IL (Intermediate Language)...optimized or non-optimized....controlled by whether your project sets the `DEBUG` flag or not
- At the JITer level
  ...when the IL is translated into machine code (either through Just-in-Time compilation or via NGEN)....optimized machine code may or may not be produced
  Note: it is NOT the IL produced via the compiler in DEBUG or RELEASE mode that controls the JITter optimization setting...it's an independent setting.

The main optimization "wins" occur at the JIT level.

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/57db50f1-54c7-4730-a097-c4976bb3a30b/

When you are debugging a NET program through Visual Studio, normally you don't want the JITter to produce optimized machine code, because then your program source statements aren't closely in sync with the executing code when you step through it.

So that's why there is an option in Visual Studio to turn off JITter optimizations (this is comparable to turning off JITter optimizations with the `AllowOptimize=0` flag)...and by default Visual Studio turns JITter optimizations off:

[image]

See this for an explanation of the Suppress option:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241594(v=vs.85).aspx

When you run a NET application outside of Visual Studio it doesn't matter if that program was compiled as DEBUG (non-optimized IL) or RELEASE (optimized IL)....the JITter will produce optimized machine code by default.

> So the behaviour to be noticed is that a NET program will run
>   substantially faster when started outside of Visual Studio than when
>   started from Visual Studio due to the different JITter optimization
>   setting...even when it's a RELEASE mode application....as @Knasterbax
>   observed. In addition, there's additional overhead to add when debugging (F5) and not just running (CTRL+F5) from Visual Studio.

If you run your application (whether RELEASE or DEBUG) from Explorer and then you "attach" to the process with Visual Studio, then your application will be using a JITter that is applying optimizations....your code will run faster...but any source code stepping will not be in sync.

If you untick the "Suppress JIT optimizations" then you can gain faster execution at the expense of a poorer debugging experience in Visual Studio.

---

To end, there is a way to turn off JITter Optimizations for your application code should you need/want to:

- disable JITter for entire application by putting this into app.config

> [.NET Framework Debugging Control]
>  AllowOptimize=0

- you can tell the JITter not to optimize specified methods by using this attribute

> [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoOptimization)]

on method bodies.

Comment: Nice hint! By default VS suppresses JIT-optimization in debug mode. But if you are debugging time-consuming code over and over again it can be helpful to switch on optimization...

Answer (score 3):

F5 is start debugging, not "run", it will be doing a lot of things like loading symbols in the background, even if you're attempting to debug a release build.

Answer (score 0):

When you compile the code in debug mode, the compiler switches off some optimisations, and it adds some extra instructions, to make it possible to put breakpoints everywhere and to make it possible to single step through the code.

This will make code compiled in debug mode slower than code compiled in release mode.